# listagg Oracle SQL Query, join on same table

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

For every dog, I'd like to find the matching names of other animals besides dog, and add them in a comma-separated list. Images of table and desired results of query below:

A table exists with this structure:
[image]

And I would like to create a query with results such as:
[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `self-join` and then a `listagg`.

```
select tdog.animal,tdog.name
,listagg(tother.animal||'-'||tother.name||'-'||tother.id) within group(order by tother.id)
from tablename tdog
join tablename tother on tdog.name=tother.name and tdog.animal='dog' and tother.animal <> 'dog'
group by tdog.animal,tdog.name
```

Answer (score 0):

With some tricks, you don't need a `self join`:

```
select 'dog' as animal, name,
       listagg(case when animal <> 'dog' then animal || '-' || name || '-' || id
               end), ',') within group (order by id) as animals
from t
group by name
having sum(case when animal = 'dog' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```